# Wrote stack traces to tombstoned on Android 13 using NFC Manager plugin in flutter app. and permission denial

Tags: flutter, nfc, java.lang.class, react-native-nfc-manager

I am trying to lock the tag using the nfcmanager facing issue while locking. once session is getting started for handling tag lock feature after that when it go to the locking function application is getting stoped and not responding.

I/abgroup.nfclabs(15408): Thread[5,tid=15413,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb400007bc1699dd0,peer=0x13780260,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/abgroup.nfclabs(15408):
I/abgroup.nfclabs(15408): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
F/crash_dump64(16414): crash_dump.cpp:540] failed to attach to thread 641: Permission denied

i am trying to lock the tag using the nfc manager. but it is not working with andriod 13 same with andriod 12 it is working

Comment: You need to show your code for people to help. There was a change in Android 12L which introduced a new Security Exception if you were using NFC incorrectly, may be the thread has died because of that and cannot be attached to because it does not exist any more (I would check the logs for it).

Comment: yes, sure problem is with the write lock feature or may some other feature of the nfc compitablity with the andriod 13 as the same issue i am facing with sampe github code avilable for nfc_manager package on pub.dev.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager/example here is the link of the sample code avilable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.